# SwiftUI Grid view is broken in split view

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, uisplitviewcontroller, swiftui-list

I would look to show 2 column grid in all devices, while it works as expected in all devices and orientation except when ipad have split view it is broken.

**Expected result**

[image]

**Actual result**

[image]

Below is the code

```
let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 48)/2)),
        GridItem(.fixed((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 48)/2))
    ]
```

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [columns]) {
// customize grid
}}
```

The root problem exists at column property, it takes the screen value but in split mode it should take its own view size. I am wondering how to handle this property in swiftui

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would suggest using the `.flexible` item instead of the `.fixed` one. And would avoid accessing `UIScreen.main.bounds` because your view doesn't take up the whole screen.

Comment: how one can properly define minimum and maximum sizes in flexible? I mean there are several devices and orientations combinations out there @EmilioPelaez

Comment: Please update your question with a [mre] so an answerer can be sure that there isn't another variable at play with your cells or layout. As the first comment suggests, `.flexible` is likely the right choice here.